# GTK2 C - how to pass 2D array of structures to callback function and change this array's values?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gtk

I'm writing an app (Battleships puzzle) in GTK+ in C. I have a structure *shippart*:

```
typedef enum {
    water, single, top, bot, mid, left, right, waterU, shipU, unknown
} shiptype;

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *img;
    shiptype type; //shiptype is typedef enum
    shiptype hiddenType;
} shippart;
```

The whole map is two-dimensional array of shippart (`shippart battlemap[10][10]`) and I have it declared in my `main()`. I fill all these 3 fields, user clicks on a single part (1 of 100) of the map to mark it as water or as a ship part. When he wants to check if his guesses are correct, he should be able to click 'Check' which, if his guesses were correct, will change his water-marked parts as water, ship-marked parts as (more specified) ship parts and if he did something wrong, it will unmark it.

Everything is fine until the point of checking. It just doesn't work and I assume it's caused by something with passing this map array.

```
void buttonCheckHandler(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data) {
    //this is most likely wrong, I found it somewhere in the other question here
    //but honestly I tried everything and it just doesn't work
    shippart * (*map)[MAP_SIZE] = (shippart *(*)[MAP_SIZE])user_data;

    //this part might be unnecessary
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i<MAP_SIZE; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j<MAP_SIZE; j++) {
            if(map[i][j]->type == waterU) {
                if(map[i][j]->hiddenType == water) {
                    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(map[i][j]->img), shiptypes[0]);
                    map[i][j]->type = water;
                }
                else {
                    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(map[i][j]->img), shiptypes[9]);
                    map[i][j]->type = unknown;
                }
                continue;
            }
            //... very similar lines to these 11 above
        }
    }
}

void makeOverlay(shippart map[][MAP_SIZE], (...)) {
    //...
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(btnCheck), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(buttonCheckHandler), &map);
    //...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    shippart battlemap[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE]; 
    fillMap(battlemap); //fills hiddenType's
    makeUserMap(battlemap); //fills type's with 'unknown' and 2-4 fields with those from hiddenType
    makeOverlay(battlemap, (...)); //almost everything with gtk
}
```

So my question is: how to correctly pass this map from makeOverlay() to buttonCheckHandler()? Is it even possible? I used to have `shippart map[10][10]` as global variable and it worked (my `buttonCheckHandler` was like this:)

```
void buttonCheckHandler(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data) {
    checkMap(); //without parameteres, because it changed global variable
    //I tried same thing with checkMap(user_data); earlier but it didn't work
}
```

but my code was pretty horrible to read and undestand and now I messed it up. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a 2D array and an array of pointers (aka *ragged* 2D array).

When passing a 2D array, it decays to a pointer to the first element. You can access the data through the pointer by treating it as a 1D array, but you must calculate the index.

```
shippart * map = user_data;

...

map[i*MAP_SIZE+j].type;
//or
(map+i*MAP_SIZE+j)->type;
```

---

As for messing up your source when making big changes, you should use a version control system. One of the most widely available (and primitive) is RCS, which can work with single files, too. Whenever you make a change and get it to compile and run correctly, *check-in* the source. With RCS, it's

```
ci -l filename.c
```

The `-l` immediately extracts a new editable file after checking it in. Then if you make bad changes, you can revert to the previous checked-in version with

```
ls filename.c,v  # <-- before deleting, make sure you actually have a checked-in file
rm filename.c
co -l filename.c
```

Comment: I changed it the way you wrote, but result is still the same - it doesn't work (and by this I mean nothing changes when I click "Check"). I used debugger and there is literally crap in map[] (inside `buttonCheckHandler()`). Everything is fine after placing ships (I printed both .type and .hiddenType), when you click on the map value in .type is changed, but nothing works inside `buttonCheckHandler()`. Any other ideas?